# PHP Determined HTML Classes

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to determine the best way of using PHP to assign the classes of my tabbed menu items.

What I've read so far on the subject here and elsewhere seems to only determine very simplistic cases.  I need to have an active class for the tab when you're on it's page and I also need a disabled class for the tab on accounts without access to that feature (based on a session flag).

Originally, I just echoed out everything like this:

```
 <?php  
    echo '<li class="some-tab ';if($pageName === "somepage.php"){echo'active';}
            if(!$_SESSION['some_flag']){echo'disabled';
            echo'"><a href="">Link</a>';}
   ?>
```

But then code shame set in and I'm trying to really start using PHP like templating engine.  That said, I do not want to use an actual templating engine.

For any other part of the HTML, hopping in and out of PHP is easy and relatively elegant, but when it comes to getting classes to work, it's feels clunky.  It completely pollutes the markup and leaves me with way too much logic in my template.

Like so:

```
<li class="some-tab <? if($pageName === "somepage.php"){echo'active';} ?></li>
```

Not terrible but add a few more rules and it becomes a mess.

My first thought is creating an associative array and just echoing it's contents:

```
<?  if(some condition){
       $class = array("sometab" => "sometab active disabled");
    }
    else{
       $class = array("sometab" => "sometab");
    }
 ?>
<li class="<?= $class['sometab'] ?>"> </li>
```

But I feel like it may be [too clever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

I want to avoid storing information in the body class or as Javascript cookies as suggested by some because I'm not just fetching the URL.

Is there an option I'm missing?

Is a class array appropriate in the slightest?  I don't have the experience to know if it's a horrible idea or not.

Comment: Sounds like you need to start looking into PHP frameworks if you're not already using one. Then you could run all your checks in the controller and just pass a variable to the view which adds the required class in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying. Your first two examples had conditionals based on the `$pagename` and a session variable, but your associative array example doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: @Barmar You're right.  I was trying to communicate that I would do the logic somewhere else.  I clarified that.

Comment: @diggersworld I would agree with you, but it's just not possible at the moment.  That's why I want to avoid implementing a templating engine for the moment.  When I finally can implement a decent framework, I'll switch to templating, but until then, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @MobyD: Sure, be aware you don't have to implement your own there are loads freely available like CodeIgniter, Kohana, etc. It would be foolish to write your own when there's so many available, unless you're purely doing it as a learning experience.

Comment: @diggersworld I really do love the frameworks out there and can't wait until I can implement them.  But there are some components to the application that I have zero control over so I'm currently left slapping together my own "framework" and "templating engine".

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered this yourself.

You need a *templating engine* if you want it to run like a *templating engine*

With that said, something you might find neat though, is shorthand logic statements:

```
if($x > 10){echo 'BlahBlah';}else{ echo 'NahNah';}
```

turns into:

```
echo ($x>10?'BlahBlah':'NahNah');
```

these can come in handy in logic gates like the ones you are mentioning

Comment: And along with this you can use PHP's `<?= expression ?>` shorthand, which does the `echo` for you. It starts to look like a template language when you do this.

Comment: @barmar yeah almost forgot about that. You might need to enable `<?= ?>` shorthand on your server though

Comment: this. just use a templating engine!

Comment: @RCorrie I made sure to do that before hand.  I do like ternary, I just wish I could concatenate strings (like with .=) using it.  Without that, it makes this a lot harder.  As far as templating is concerned, there are very complex reasons I'm currently not doing it...but those reasons seem to be weakening the more I work on this code.

Comment: @MobyD Why dont you write a function that validates the page you are in and returns a flag? That would keep your main code clean and simple, while the chicken scratch is put away?

Answer (score 0):

Your last option would be the most elegant for me. Anyway, if you can use a MVC pattern with some Framework, I would strongly recommend it to you.

In any case, it is very probable you will have to deal with this stuff at some point inside the template if you dont want to create variables for each CSS style.